# Android app is open on browser when I redirect form an url

Tags: android

I'm trying to open an android app when I tap a URL inside an email. It's working well the app is opening, the problem is when I use the "Internet Browser" it opens the android on the browser, that means I will have two instances of the Android app. This doesn't happen using Chrome browser, it only calls the app, it doesn't open on the browser.

**I resolved this problem using:** 
android:launchMode="singleInstance" and android:launchMode="singleTask"
but I'm not able to reach the parameters from the URL tapped to open the app.

**URL structure:** email://act/parameter1/parameter2

This is my code:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Login"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:exported="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="act" android:scheme="email" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In conclusion, I would like to open the app only with one instance (not on the browser) and be able to reach the parameters, using any browser (Chrome, Internet, Firefox).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The latest statement in question is unclear. Could you please share more details. What does it mean " _able to reach the parameters, using any browser (Chrome, Internet, Firefox)._" Do you want to receive parameters from link clicked and then open browser using them?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get the parameters from the Url. This Url opens the android app and it has the parameters too. The problem is when I tap on the Url using then Internet browser (not Firefox, not Chrome) is open the Android app on the browser. I don't want this. This behaviour doesn't happen using Chrome.

Comment: What do you mean by "open Android app on the browser"? Do you mean that click on a link will open some other app on top of your app?

Comment: In my phone, I have two browsers (Chrome and Internet). When I using the Internet Browser, I tap on the Url to open my Android app, this Url is opening my app in the browser, it's not calling my app. But, when I using the Chrome browser, it's calling my Android app and my is not opening in the browser

Comment: So your app is a website?

Comment: My app is a native android app

Comment: I can't get it ) you told that your app is openning in the browser - how native app could be opened in browser? It's web browser or not. I'm totally confused (

Comment: yes, man this is my problem. I don't understand why. The only way to solve it, It's using android:launchMode="singleInstance" and android:launchMode="singleTask", but applying this, I can't get the parameters from the Url

Comment: Where are you receive an Intent with Url and how do You parse it? In Activity `onCreate` and in `onNewIntent()`?

Comment: In onCreate, I'm putting this code:
if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
    String f0 = params.get(0);
    String f1 = params.get(1);
}

Comment: So here is the problem - you need to override `onNewIntent()` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your activity code, but i will try to guess the problem: If your activity is a `singleTask` you need to handle incomming Intents in `onCreate()` **and** in `onNewIntent()` . This is because `Activity` will be created only once and each next incoming Intent will be then handled by `onNewIntent()`